# Eigen Transformations: Why do high eigenvalues indicate regions of text?

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, eigenvalue, eigen

Many papers mention that text regions give rise to high eigenvalues calculated from the greylevel pixel values after the image has been divided into blocks of mxm matrices. Also that eigenvalues are a measure of the 'roughness' of the texture of the image.

How is that related to getting text? Text areas are generally of two colors, background and foreground with the letter-strokes of uniform color. Where is this roughness - there could be many other features that would be more rough and trigger high eigenvalues. Could someone point out where to get the math that connects these things?

**EDITS:**
A few papers included that mention eigenvalues in the context of text detection in natural scenes.

1. [A framework towards realtime detection and tracking of text](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.102.3729&rep=rep1&type=pdf) uses the Eigentransform on greyscale image.
2. [An eigenvalue-based approach to text detection in video](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1815395) mentions calculating eigenvalues from the covariance matrix of gradient image.

Comment: This is way to vague to answer properly, but one explanation would be that the foreground comprises a large number of thin lines, so that there is no large expanse of either color.

Comment: If you ask about statements made in papers, you should cite these papers. Doesn't have to be a link to be retrievable.

Comment: eigenvalues of what? of the image (as a matrix), of a correlation matrix, or of what?

Comment: @leonbloy - eigenvalues of the image as a matrix, also of covariance matrix of the gradient image as mentioned in different approaches in papers. However all point to the fact that text gives rise to high eigenvalues as a way of differentiating text/non-text regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an orientation, so you can start reading and eventually target your next question better:

You are talking about [**Principal Component Analysis**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)

Here you have an example application:

[image]

HTH to get you started.

Comment: thanks. I was reading up on PCA analysis, but mostly related to the math not specifically figuring out the text-to-high-eigenvalue concept. Will read some more.

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=EGj9lLiRK1wC&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=Eigen+transform+texture&source=bl&ots=oeAYv7eKBa&sig=blOuAOjUlTf4s0Nuu5Ji3_jHMV8&hl=en&ei=H3fpTfmFBZHyvQOnsqTBDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Eigen%20transform%20texture&f=false

Comment: thats the link to where the Eigen Transform is explained in detail. a pretty long hiatus but all doubts now rest in peace. :)